# DBMaker connection with PHP ODBC (using PDO)

Tags: php, yii2, odbc

I'm developing an application with a php framework (Yii) who use pdo connection also for [remote ODBC databases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#creating-db-connections).

I'm working on a Debian server with PHP 7.1, with DBMaker drivers installed, ODBC.ini configured so DBMaker works well with this code:

```
if(!odbc_connect('MYDBDSN','myuser', 'mypass')) {
   echo "Connection not found " . odbc_errormsg();
} else {
   echo "Database exists";
}
// queries works!
```

But a connection made by

```
$conn =   new PDO ("odbc:MYDBDSN", 'myuser', 'mypass');
```

says *Unable to connect; PDOException: could not find driver*.

Is there any way to connect my DBMaker database with PDO, making my queries *framework compatible*?

Comment: have you uncommented it in `php.ini`

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam, you brought me on the right path

Comment: you are welcome brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to [install](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php-pdo-odbc) and [configure](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) `pdo_odbc` drivers for PHP.

[This link](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/103#issuecomment-252818020) can be useful if your servers works under a Docker environment.